# How to use class static initialization blocks in Javascript?

Tags: javascript, static

I was wondering if anyone could explain this example from the MDN docs:

```js
let getDPrivateField;

class D {
  #privateField;
  constructor(v) {
    this.#privateField = v;
  }
  static {
    getDPrivateField = (d) => d.#privateField;
  }
}

getDPrivateField(new D('private'));
//private
```

I understand that each static block is defined on the class and executed when the class constructor declaration is evaluated. What I don't understand is how `main` has access to the `getDPrivateField` arrow function outside of its definition within the constructor. Doesn't class create its own scope and variables declared within are local variables? Shouldn't there be two versions of `getDPrivateField` and the one outside of the `D` class constructor is undefined?

Comment: Inside of the static block is normal JS code, not a special syntax.

Comment: `getPrivateField` is *only* a variable declared in the first line of the code block. The static block assigns a value to it.

Comment: Oh it's just a code block not a special property space. That answers my question, thanks.